# Changing font of Xperia SP stock Clock Widget

Tags: fonts, sony-xperia-sp

I rooted my Xperia SP and managed to change all fonts to Roboto Condensed.
Only issue I am having is with the clock widget. I am not sure which font is used by the stock clock widget.
I managed to change the time font of the clock widget to Roboto Condensed.
I changed Time font by replacing `.SST-UltraLight.ttf` with Roboto Condensed font.

But can't change the font of Date and Alarm information. It uses some other font.

Can anybody help me on this?

[image: Lock Screen] [image: Home Screen]
<sup>Screenshots of the lock-screen (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: Part of me thinks that the widget uses it's own font built in to its package, rather than a system font.  I don't think you'll be able to change it.

Comment: I checked that too. That's how I found that it uses the font '.SST-UltraLight.ttf' I have not idea why its not getting reflected on date and alarm strings.